# A simple (indented) integration contour with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to draw an integration contour which is pretty easy I think, but I am a newbie at the Tikz package. The integration contour goes from

-i*infinity to +i*infinity

parallel to the Imaginary axis but not exactly on it, rather slightly to the left (or right) of it. The integration contour also has a semicircle on it somewhere near the origin but not exactly on the origin.

I guess I'm looking for an indented contour but not the usual ones where one go from -infinity to + infinity with a jump over a pole as in the following picture 
[image: contour]
but like I said I would like it to go vertically.

[image: Indented contour]

I also found this picture, I want something very close to this. If I get some help getting what is in the picture in the link I think I can manage doing the rest myself.

[indented integration contour](http://math.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/integralsindentedcontour/IntegralsIndentedContourModHome/Links/IntegralsIndentedContourModHome_lnk_4.html)

Please, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Not sure of what you want. Could you provide a hand-made sketch? Also, perhaps this question can help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103176/drawing-complex-integration

Comment: Hey JLDiaz I just added a link with a picture. That's pretty close to what I want. Any suggestions where to start? Thanks.

Comment: @Zkit TeX syntax doesn't work on TeX-SX. It's a deliberate choice. So `$$` is just noise.

Comment: OK that sucks, but I fixed it now.

Comment: Zkit any reason for reverting back the edits?

Comment: I haven't reverted any edits? I just edited it myself adding a link, at the same time I think someone else was editing.

Comment: Look at the history of edits

Comment: I think it looks nice now, but I can change something if you don't like it and can't change it. I just want to solve this contour problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a first approximation, based on the answer to the question [Drawing complex integration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103176/drawing-complex-integration).

Is this close to what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,-5.5) -- (0,5.5);  % Axis
\draw (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0);   
\foreach \y in {-5,...,5} {
  \draw (-4pt,\y) -- (4pt,\y) node[pos=0,left] {\y};
  \draw (\y,-4pt) -- (\y,4pt) node[pos=0,below] {\y};
}

\node at (0,-1.5) {$\times$}; % Pole

% Contour line
\draw[thick,red,xshift=2pt,
decoration={ markings,  % This schema allows for fine-tuning the positions of arrows
      mark=at position 0.2 with {\arrow{latex}}, 
      mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow{latex}},
      mark=at position 0.8 with {\arrow{latex}}, 
      mark=at position 0.98 with {\arrow{latex}}}, 
      postaction={decorate}]
  (0,-5) -- (0,-1.7) arc (-90:90:.2) -- (0,5);
\draw[thick,red,xshift=2pt,
decoration={ markings,
      mark=at position 0.2 with {\arrow{latex}}, 
      mark=at position 0.4 with {\arrow{latex}},
      mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow{latex}}, 
      mark=at position 0.8 with {\arrow{latex}}}, 
      postaction={decorate}]
 (0,5) arc (90:-90:5) -- (0,-5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Ohh that's beautiful brother, thank you for your effort! I will soon fill in with comments, let me just play around with your example for a minute. Thanks again bro.

Comment: For the markings at regular intervals, TikZ provides `mark=between positions .2 and .8 step .2 with \arrow{latex}`. For the irregular marking I’d define an style `mark at` as follows: `\pgfset{decoration/mark at/.style 2 args={@mark/.style={mark=at position ##1 with {#2}},@mark/.list={#1}}}` that can be used as `mark at={.2,.6,.8,.98}{\arrow{latex}}}` in the `decoration` key. (You can also use it for regular markings: `mark at={.1,.2,...,.9}{\arrow{latex}}`.)