# How to draw following complex integration?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am new to tikz package and want to draw following complex integration contours. I would like to insert these two pictures in my report. I read the previous posts on similar drawings but can't figure out the way to modify the existing code. Can some one help me out? Thank you very much. Here are the plots:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: In addition, how to save the picture as a eps or pdf with appropriate margin good for insert to the report? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your question leaves all the effort to our community, even typing the essentials of a TeX document such as `\documentclass{}...\begin{document}` etc. As it is, most of our users will be very reluctant to touch your question, and you are left to the mercy of our procrastination team who are very few in number and very picky about selecting questions. You can improve your question by adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that more users can copy/paste onto their systems to work on. If no hero takes the challenge we might have to close your question.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130987/a-simple-indented-integration-contour-with-tikz

Comment: and this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103176/drawing-complex-integration?lq=1