# changing fontsize in pstricks

Tags: line-breaking, pstricks, fontsize

I'd like to create a contour diagram based off the following template

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}

\psset
{
        PointName=none,
        PointSymbol=none,
        linecap=1,
        linecolor=red,
}

\def\Radius{1.8}
\def\radius{0.5}
\def\Angle{2.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none,linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(2.7,2.7)[$\textbf{Re}\, z$,-90][$\textbf{Im}\, z$,180]
    \pstGeonode 
        (0,0){O}
        (\Radius;\Angle){A}
        (\Radius;90){B}
        (\Radius;-90){C}
        (\Radius;-\Angle){D}
        (\radius;0|D){E}
        (\radius;0|A){F}
    \pstArcOAB[arrows=->,arcsepB=-3pt]{O}{A}{B}
    \pstArcOAB[arrows=->,arcsepB=-3pt]{O}{B}{C}
    \pstArcOAB{O}{C}{D}
    \pstLineAB[ArrowInside=->]{D}{E}
    \pstArcnOAB{O}{E}{F}
    \pstLineAB[ArrowInside=->]{F}{A}
    %labeling
    \psset{labelsep=2pt}
    \uput[45](\Radius;45){$\Gamma$}
    \uput[135](\radius;135){$\gamma$}
    \uput[-45](\Radius;0){$R$}
    \uput[-135](\Radius;180){$-R$}  
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

which I borrowed from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103176/drawing-complex-integration?lq=1). The problem is the font is too big. Is there a way to set the fontsize/family globally so that it would apply to the entire file?

Actually, one more question: I'd like to use \psComment for annotations, but I wasn't able to figure out how make multiline annotations. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: For the second part (multiline annotations), you can use a `\parbox`, as in     `\psComment[ref=l,angleA=180](1,-1)(0,0){\parbox{4cm}{\large Origin \\ more text}}[\ncdiagg]`.

Comment: Thanks, I've also found another solution: to use \shortstack[c]{Line 1\\Line 2}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simply: add, say, `footnotesize` to your code:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up increasing the dimensions of the picture (by adjusting xunit/yunit). That made the font appear in scale with everything else in the picture.

Comment: That's the simplest thing to do indeed. Note choosing a font size for figures slightly smaller than current font size looks fine usually.